# Dark theme for chrome DevTools from command line

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any flag which I can use to run Chrome browser from terminal, with will enable dark theme for DevTools?

Comment: I see no switch for this. The setting itself is stored in `Preferences` file (JSON path is devtools.preferences.uiTheme).

Comment: Thank you, I could not found it either. It would be useful for e.g. I am using Karma for my unit tests, which opens Chrome and conducting tests. When I want to debug my tests in browser, I have to change theme manually all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about specifying the user data directory, and pointing it to a profile that has dark theme enabled?

Just worked on my Mac:

```
--user-data-dir ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome\ Canary/Profile\ 4
```

See [How to specify command line flags](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/command-line-flags) for those who don't know how to launch Chrome from the command line.

Open a profile and go to `chrome://version` to see the location of that user profile directory (under `Profile Path`).